# Snowflake take the median of the string of list

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

My table is like this :

| first | second |
| --- | --- |
| A | [10,20,30] |
| B | [40,50,60] |

I want to add third column which takes median or mean of the second column, second column's type is string, how can i do in snowflake ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `second` column value would always be a string array having three comma separated elements, we could try a regex replacement here:

```sql
SELECT first, second, REGEXP_REPLACE(second, '^.*?,|,.*$', '') AS third
FROM yourTable;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

Here is a working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=30c09aeedfc8f1d42fb1623d10f645d6) (given in MySQL 8, but should work equally well on Snowflake).

Comment: It is ok for median, but how can i get the mean of string ?

Comment: I don't know how to do that.  You rather should change your table design and stop storing CSV data like this.  Instead, get each array value onto a separate row.  Or, use an actual type that supports arrays, such as JSON.

Comment: I want to ask extra question, if the list is not sorted, how can i make ? Can regex sort the list ?

Answer (score 0):

So if you just want the "middle token" you can use:

With this fake data in a CTE:

```
with data(first, second) as (
    select column1, parse_json(column2) 
    from values
        ('A','[10,20,30]'),
        ('B','[40,50,60]'),
        ('D','[]'),
        ('E','[100]'),
        ('F','[400,500]'),
        ('G','[400,500,600]'),
        ('H','[400,500,700,800]'),
        ('I','[400,500,700,800,900]')
)
```

this SQL gives:

```
select d.first
    ,d.second
    ,array_size(d.second) as s
    ,(s/2)::int -1 as p
    ,d.second[p] as middle_value
from data as d
order by 1;
```

| FIRST | SECOND | S | P | MIDDLE_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | [ 10, 20, 30 ] | 3 | 1 | 20 |
| B | [ 40, 50, 60 ] | 3 | 1 | 50 |
| D | [] | 0 | -1 | null |
| E | [ 100 ] | 1 | 0 | 100 |
| F | [ 400, 500 ] | 2 | 0 | 400 |
| G | [ 400, 500, 600 ] | 3 | 1 | 500 |
| H | [ 400, 500, 700, 800 ] | 4 | 1 | 500 |
| I | [ 400, 500, 700, 800, 900 ] | 5 | 2 | 700 |

which can be reformed as:

```
select d.first
    ,d.second
    ,d.second[(array_size(d.second)/2)::int -1] as middle_value
from data as d
order by 1;
```

Or you can flatten the data, and just use the [MEDIAN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/median.html) function:

```
select d.first
    ,MEDIAN(f.value) as median_value
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d.second)) f
group by d.first, f.seq
order by 1;
```

with the same CTE gives:

| FIRST | MEDIAN_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 50 |
| E | 100 |
| F | 450 |
| G | 500 |
| H | 600 |
| I | 700 |

The second form has the merit of allowing other functions to also be used:

```
select d.first
    ,MEDIAN(f.value) as median_value
    ,AVG(f.value) as avg_value
    ,STDDEV(f.value) as stddev_value
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d.second)) f
```

| FIRST | MEDIAN_VALUE | AVG_VALUE | STDDEV_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 20 | 10 |
| B | 50 | 50 | 10 |
| E | 100 | 100 | null |
| F | 450 | 450 | 70.710678119 |
| G | 500 | 500 | 100 |
| H | 600 | 600 | 182.574185835 |
| I | 700 | 660 | 207.364413533 |

lastly the D row, as it has no value produces no output, this can be fixed by using the `OUTER => TRUE` option of [FLATTEN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten.html)

```
select d.first
    ,MEDIAN(f.value) as median_value
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d.second, outer=>true)) f
group by d.first, f.seq
order by 1;
```

now D is present:

| FIRST | MEDIAN_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 20 |
| B | 50 |
| D | null |
| E | 100 |
| F | 450 |
| G | 500 |
| H | 600 |
| I | 700 |

Comment: What if input is varchar.It gives an error about 'invalid type [VARCHAR(16777216)] for parameter 'input''

Comment: If you “array” is a single string split with split or split_to_table, after that the parts should be cast thus try_to_number then math onwards.